# What is the Drupal 8 equivalent of Drupal 7's "drupal_add_html_head" within a module?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I'm creating some custom modules for Drupal 8. They include some header modification for better Facebook integration. Here is what it looked like in Drupal 7 (SEVEN):

```
    $element1 = array
        (
        '#tag' => 'meta',
        '#attributes' => array
            ( 
            'property' => 'og:title',
            'content' => " Profile: " . $record->NameFirst . " " . $record->NameLast,
            ),
        );
    drupal_add_html_head($element1, 'og_title');
```

But this drupal_add_html_head function is long long gone in Drupal 8. And I'm quite lost as to where to START attacking this. Maybe it's "Headerbag"? There's a Headerbag::add. Maybe it's in the module's return variable, possibly adding another element somewhere here:

```
return array(
  '#markup' => t($pageContent),
);
```

Maybe HtmlResponseAttachmentsProcessor::setHeaders? HeaderBag::set? Session::setRequestHeader? PoStreamWriter::setHeader? PoMetadataInterface::setHeader?

Unfortunately, I can find pretty much no examples of how these are used. And I'm sure everyone here is familiar with the annoyance of having code that *does work* in previous versions that morphs into "doesn't work with no solution" in new code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `your_module_page_attachments` hook. For example if you want to adjust the og:image tag you could do the following:

```
function your_module_page_attachments(array &$page) {
    $ogImage = array(
        '#tag' => 'meta',
        '#attributes' => array(
            'property' => 'og:image',
            'content' => url to your image,
        ),
    );

    $page['#attached']['html_head'][] = [$ogImage, 'ogImage'];
}
```

Hook information: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Render!theme.api.php/function/hook_page_attachments/8.2.x

Comment: Is there additional work in the routing.yml to trigger the call to your_module_page_attachments?

Comment: No, you create a "your_module.module" file, where "your_module" is of course the name of your module. In that file you declare the function from above, again replace "your_module" with your module name. Then just clear the cache and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

The preferred replacement is to use the `#attached` property in the build array.

```
$build['#attached']['html_head'][] = array(
...
);
```

Here is the change record detailing this: https://www.drupal.org/node/2160069

Comment: THanks.  Does it say something about Drupal that I get an answer 5 years later, after the site in question has been migrated to version 9? :( Honestly, I can't remember if I got it working, and I can only suspect FB has gotten ever more closed in their approach to integrating external content. 

Comment: There is dedicated site for Drupal answers : https://drupal.stackexchange.com